# Why do Ran and Heiji wear the same clothes?

Tags: detective-conan

When Kazuha first appeared in *Detective Conan* series, she notices that Ran and Heiji wear the same clothes each time they met.

What is the idea of this? They are not in love. Is their strong relation with Shinichi related?

Answer (score 2):

It was a coincidence, but it served as a plot point to showcase Ran's personality: when Kazuha accused her of purposely wearing the same clothes as Heiji, she replied by removing her shirt even though she was sitting in a car in a public space.